# Jquery validation dropdown list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

Dropdownlist:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-3" class="control-label">Priority</label>
        <select id="lstpriority" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Validate:

```
$("#frmAddEdit").validate({
    lstpriority: {
        required: {
            depends: function (element) {
                return $("#lstpriority").val() == "";
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        lstpriority: {
            required: "Please select an option from the list",
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        abc();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Drop down binding:

```
function bindPrioritytype() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AdminWeb.asmx/GetLOV',
        data: 'id=0&type=PRIORITYTYPELOV',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#lstpriority").append("").val("").html("");
            $("#lstpriority").append($("<option></option>").val("").html("Select"));
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                $("#lstpriority").append($("<option></option>").val(val.TB_ID).html(val.TB_NAME));
            });
            $('#lstpriority').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    });
}
```

I am not able to validate dropdownlist on submit even i tried adding class required as well.I want to validate the dropdownlist, Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You tagged this question with ASP.   Does this mean you're  using the unobtrusive plugin too?   If so, you cannot call `.validate()` since unobtrusive already did this for you.  Yours will always be ignored.

Comment: Otherwise, you **must** have a name attribute and the rule is declared within `rules` object using this name.

Comment: I am not using unobtrusive plugin i have added the name attribute but still not getting the error message can you give me one example?

Comment: One example?   There are over six thousand examples posted on SO!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
lstpriority: {required: true}
```

instead of

```
lstpriority: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#lstpriority").val() == "";
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Nothing to do with it.  He can't call `.validate()` while he's also using the unobtrusive plugin.  He also needs to have `name="lstpriority"` attribute on the input element.

Comment: if not using unobtrusive plugin then it will work with assigning class to dropdown with class="required"

Comment: Regardless, he is missing the `name` attribute and this plugin **will** fail without it.

Comment: i think name attribute wont make plugin fail unless can't modify the error message of .validate()

Comment: Wrong.  The name attribute is always mandatory.  Just look at the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Use this piece of code. You can also declare some default selection like Choose.. or Select and in `valueNotEquals: ""` and you can change this to `valueNotEquals: "Select"`

Complete Code

```
 // configure your validation on a list
 $("#frmAddEdit").validate({
  rules: {
   lstpriority: { valueNotEquals: "" }
  },
  messages: {
   lstpriority: { valueNotEquals: "Please select an item!" }
  }  
 });
```

Comment: i tried this it is not showing me the error message.

Comment: try with {min:1} in rule for ist

Comment: Nothing to do with it.  He can't call `.validate()` while he's also using the unobtrusive plugin.  He also needs to have `name="lstpriority"` attribute on the input element.